# Product ordered but was out of stock

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, inventory

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have configured my store not to allow backorders, but for some reason some products are ordered having the stock at 0.

I'm using Paypal for the payment process.

**Catalog -> Inventory Settings:**

- Decrease Stock When Order is Placed => Yes

  - Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled => Yes
  - Display Out of Stock Products => Yes
  - Only X left Threshold => 0
  - Manage Stock => Yes
  - Backorders => No Backorders

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you also check store level settings?

Comment: when a product is at 0 the product isnt shown on the frontend, but for some reason the customer was able to make that order...Which settings are you refer to?

Comment: The configuration settings & stock settings for your store.

Comment: i've have set the manage stock to yes.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am kind of in same situation.